# Reselect text in content editable div after re-rendering - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have content editable div and a button. I want to achieve the follow

- Select a text in the div
- When I press the button to preserve the selection and then replace the selected text by a span whose content is the selected text
- Preserve the selection for further edits.

So far I have the following code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState("<p>Hello World!</p>");
  const [selectionRange, setSelectionRange] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectionRange) {
      let range = new Range();
      range.setStart(document.querySelector(".text-bold").firstChild, 0);
      range.setEnd(
        document.querySelector(".text-bold").firstChild,
        document.querySelector(".text-bold").firstChild.length
      );

      let sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }, [htmlContent]);

  const storeSelectionRange = () => {
    if (window.getSelection().toString().length) {
      const sel = window.getSelection();
      const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      setSelectionRange(range);
    }
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    if (selectionRange) {
      // Restore selection
      let sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(selectionRange);

      // Create a new html element with the selected text as its content
      const newNode = document.createElement("span");
      newNode.className = "text-bold";
      const newContent = document.createTextNode(sel.toString());
      newNode.appendChild(newContent);

      // Re-select the text to be replace by the newly created element
      let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      range.insertNode(newNode);
      // setSelectionRange(range);

      // Update the html inside the content editable div with class "editor__content"
      const newHtml = document.querySelector(".content").innerHTML;
      setHtmlContent(newHtml);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="editor">
        <div
          className="content"
          contentEditable="true"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }}
          onBlur={storeSelectionRange}
        ></div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={onClick}>
          Bold
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="selected-text">{htmlContent}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I update the inner html of the div, I re-render the component to capture the html changes, and thus I need to restore the selection. However, since I insert a span in place of the original text, the saved range in `selectionRange` state variable is no longer accurate. So, what I do in `useEffect` when the html content is updated, I recreate the range object manually by selecting the span I inserted. However, the selected span is not unique, and I could have multiple spans with the same class, in which the `querySelector` will select only the first span. My question is: how to select the same text I originally selected, after I insert the span?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-snowflake-sucvp?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Honestly, selections and ranges are a nightmare. I HIGHLY RECOMMEND Tim Down's rangy project for inserting spans and applying classes. Many people (including myself) use this

Comment: Also see element.select

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I googled it and I found the github page and the documentation page. Upon skimming the docs, I found that he uses a unique identifiers for added spans around the selected text. I was actually thinking something similar, of adding a unique id for each span, and store it in a state variable, and then use it to select the most recently added span inside `useEffect`. I thought there are ready native methods I could use, though.